# Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet not working with Metamask?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, metamask, ether

Does anyone know when Rinkeby Authenticated Faucet is going to start working again?

I need to add some Ether into my Metamask wallet on the Rinkbey Test Network for testing purposes, but it seems the site is not working.

I am using my Twitter to Tweet my Metamask Ethereum address and then upon copy and pasting my Tweet address in the above website, all I see is:

[image]

Comment: The faucet is busy right now, comment your address and I will send you some

Comment: @AhmadGorji - Hi Ahmad, my address is - 0x9C020D98F3C7A981277F3CA355393280F6234DB9

Comment: Sent 5 Ethereum! Best regards :)

Comment: @Issei can you please send me some test ether as well: 0x975eBc88F08493f034289d53e89aB3a935D036CC

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kovan network, and https://ethdrop.dev/ to get the ether directly.